# Ractive with web2py (or v.v.)

Tags: javascript, html, web2py

My eyes struck Ractive.js and I want to test it with Web2py. Web2py however uses also {{ }} as the templating characters. Ractive uses these characters also. I have already a lot of Web2py apps, so changing the {{ }} markers in Ractive is the easiest for me. Can this be done?

Yes it can :

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: whatever,
  template: myTemplate,
  data: {
    greeting: 'Hello',
    greeted: 'world',
    triple: '<strong>This is a triple-stache</strong>'
  },
  delimiters: [ '[[', ']]' ],
  tripleDelimiters: [ '[[[', ']]]' ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In web2py code you can change the delimiters easily like so:

```
response.delimiters = ['{%', '%}']
```

So in the template you can have something like:

```
<body>
  {%web2py code%}
  <p>Along with</p>
  {{ember/angular/whatever code}}
</body>
```

I'd say changing the delimiters in web2py is easier, just do a find & replace across all your existing template files and you'll never have to think about it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the templates in a separate file and load it, e.g. with jQuery, you don't even need to change the delimiters.

```
 $.get("{{=URL('static','templates/hello.html')}}", function(template) {
    var ractive = new Ractive({

      el: 'container',
      template: template,
      data: { name: 'world' },

    });
});
```

because, I think, the template script is not in the scope of web2py.